# Confusing nesting of numerous #ifndef statements (with no values) in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, c-preprocessor

Maybe I'm missing something, but could some please explain the "logic" behind the following code?

```
#ifndef _PTRDIFF_T
#ifndef _T_PTRDIFF_
#ifndef _T_PTRDIFF
#ifndef __PTRDIFF_T
#ifndef _PTRDIFF_T_
#ifndef _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#ifndef ___int_ptrdiff_t_h
#ifndef _GCC_PTRDIFF_T
#define _PTRDIFF_T
#define _T_PTRDIFF_
#define _T_PTRDIFF
#define __PTRDIFF_T
#define _PTRDIFF_T_
#define _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#define ___int_ptrdiff_t_h
#define _GCC_PTRDIFF_T
#ifndef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
#endif
typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
#endif /* _GCC_PTRDIFF_T */
#endif /* ___int_ptrdiff_t_h */
#endif /* _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_ */
#endif /* _PTRDIFF_T_ */
#endif /* __PTRDIFF_T */
#endif /* _T_PTRDIFF */
#endif /* _T_PTRDIFF_ */
#endif /* _PTRDIFF_T */
```

Why is this preferred over a simple:

```
#ifndef xyz
#define xyz
#endif
```

???

I can see they are nested, but it is very confusing.  ...and btw, just what are they defining, as there are no values after the identifiers???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is to only define the macros if none of them is defiend. However, I would certainly refactor it into:

```
#if !defined(_PTRDIFF_T) && !defined(_T_PTRDIFF_) && //... well, you get the idea
  #define _PTRDIFF_T
  #define _T_PTRDIFF_
  //...
  #ifndef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__
    #define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
  #endif
  typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
#endif
```

As to the second question: you can define a macro without a replacement text (it would just expand to nothing if used). Such macros are often used for conditional inclusion of code based on `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`.

Comment: Yeah, I like your refactoring much better!  So all of the `#ifndef` entries must be TRUE before the `#define` actions are taken?

Comment: Yes, because they are nested. As soon as one of them fails (that is, one of the macros is already defined), everything up to the matching `#endif` is skipped. With regards to nesting, it works just like normal `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

They're checking that all these identifiers have been defined which would be in other already included headers. If they're all defined then we define a few new identifiers.

You don't need to give a value to the identifier, for example you wouldn't give a value to your #include guards.

Comment: I was asking more about the flow/style of the code - nested style versus the discrete `#ifndef-#endif` blocks.  Also, as I understand it, when you use `#define` without a value, you are clearing any previously set value, true?

Comment: @Les If you `#define X Y` (where `Y` can be empty) and `X` was already defined to `Y`, nothing happens. If it was defined to anything else than `Y`, it's an error.

Comment: @Les Yes, if you need to redefine a macro to something else, you use `#undef` before the `#define`.